# how can multiple payment be done with previously added card?

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I am able to get nonce by using the following codes.

```
DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
                PaymentMethodNonce nonce = result.getPaymentMethodNonce();
                String stringNonce = nonce.getNonce();
```

And I am able to call payment. 
1. Now I again want to pay amount without adding card details, how can it be done ?
2. How can I generate new nonce without adding card details ?

Answer (score 1):

[According the Braintree developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-method-nonces): "A payment method nonce is a secure, *one-time-use* reference to payment information."

You can [use the payment method nonce to create a transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale). If you do that, the nonce will be consumed and the card data with it. If you wish to securely store the card data for repeat use, you can use the nonce to [create a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create) in your [Vault](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview).

You can then retrieve the [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/#token) and use it to create transactions.